# ERROR at line 19: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "¿"

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

This procedure is getting following error.

```
create or replace procedure shedule(grad IN varchar2) as
    cursor cur(grad varchar2) is 
        select s.departments dep, s.groups gr, dis.disc_name diname, t.teach_fio teacher, s.type, s.exam_date,s.exam_time, s.kabinet
        from sessions10 s, disciplines10 dis, teachers10 t
        where dis.disc_id = s.disc_id and t.teach_id = s.teach_id 
        order by s.groups
    schrow cur%ROWTYPE;
        departments varchar2(15);
        groups      number(10);
        disciplines varchar2(15);
begin 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.enable;
    for schrow in cur(grad) LOOP
        departments := schrow.dep;
        groups := schrow.gr;
        disciplines := schrow.diname;
        dbms_output.put_line(departments||' '||groups||' '||disciplines||' '||schrow.teacher||);
    end LOOP;
end;​
```

gives:

```
ERROR at line 19: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "¿" 
1. create or replace procedure shedule(grad IN varchar2) as
2.     cursor cur(grad varchar2) is 
3.         select s.departments dep, s.groups gr, dis.disc_name diname, t.teach_fio teacher, s.type, s.exam_date,s.exam_time, s.kabinet
```

Can any one say what is wrong in this?

Thanks.

Create procedure in sql.

Comment: Line 19 seems to the final `end;` so maybe you have an invisible character there - did you copy and paste from somewhere else? Also which client is this - it might be expecting a `/` at the end, and possibly it's giving that odd error when it doesn't find it.

Comment: `order by s.groups` is missing a trailing `;`

Answer (score 0):

Two obvious errors:

- missing semi-colon in line #6
- superfluous `||` at the end of line #17

When fixed:

```
create or replace procedure shedule(grad IN varchar2) as
    cursor cur(grad varchar2) is 
        select s.departments dep, s.groups gr, dis.disc_name diname, t.teach_fio teacher, s.type, s.exam_date,s.exam_time, s.kabinet
        from sessions10 s, disciplines10 dis, teachers10 t
        where dis.disc_id = s.disc_id and t.teach_id = s.teach_id 
        order by s.groups; --> missing semi-colon
        schrow cur%ROWTYPE;
        departments varchar2(15);
        groups      number(10);
        disciplines varchar2(15);
begin 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.enable;
    for schrow in cur(grad) LOOP
        departments := schrow.dep;
        groups := schrow.gr;
        disciplines := schrow.diname;
        dbms_output.put_line(departments||' '||groups||' '||disciplines||' '||schrow.teacher);  --> superfluous ending ||
    end LOOP;
end;​
```

Though, you reported

> Encountered the symbol "¿"

Is there any *garbage* in that code? Try to delete everything that follows line #17 and type it from scratch.

Comment: It really helped to solve this problem. Thanks. Procedure created.

Answer (score 0):

There is a ZWSP character as last one in row 19.
[image]

Delete the row 19 and type **End;** with nothing else and make sure you made the corections stated in Littlefoot's answer. Do not cpoy-paste row 19 from his answer for the same is present there. You can copy first 18 rows, though, and add the 19th yourself.